# Updated Wordpress, now getting errors on site

Tags: pages, updates, homepage

I just recently updated my Wordpress, theme, and plugins, and am now getting these two errors on top of the homepage and pages page.

> Deprecated: wp_make_content_images_responsive is deprecated since
> version 5.5.0! Use wp_filter_content_tags() instead. in
> /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4773

and the pages page,

> Notice: register_rest_route was called incorrectly. The REST API route
> definition for pum/v1/analytics is missing the required
> permission_callback argument. For REST API routes that are intended to
> be public, use __return_true as the permission callback. Please see
> Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
> in version 5.5.0.) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line
> 5225

I also did this in another website but did not get any errors, the sites are built with the same theme/plugins.

Comment: Looks like one site is printing the error messages in the PHP error log, and the other is printing them to the browser output. it still needs fixing eitherway but that's why it only happens on 1 site, really it's happening on both they're just configured to handle error output differently

Comment: For the REST API route issue, iis `pum` a plugin? For `wp_make_content_images` it's difficult to answer without knowing more about the code that uses that function. Generally it sounds like your plugins and theme vendor need to release an update. In the meantime, don't print errors to the browser! Print them to the PHP error log

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is already resolved in the plugin, but I added a check for the new function in wp-content/plugins/fusion-builder/shortcodes/fusion-image.php:285.

```
if ( ! empty( $image_id ) &&  function_exists( 'wp_image_add_srcset_and_sizes' ) )  {
    $content = wp_image_add_srcset_and_sizes(
        $content,
        wp_get_attachment_metadata( (int) $image_id ),
        $image_id );
} elseif ( function_exists( 'wp_make_content_images_responsive' ) ) {
        $content = wp_make_content_images_responsive( $content );
}
```

Comment: Note to future readers: You should **never** update a plugins code as it will 100% be overwritten whenever the plugin updates.

Comment: This is 100%, absolutely true. My case is very specific where we're locked into a version.

Answer (score -2):

If nothing is broken, in your wp-config.php put this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

to get rid of the error messages

Comment: hiding the debug messages is not the way to understand and solve them.

Comment: Not, but a Notice in the core of WP is not something to fix

Comment: But the source of the notice isn't the core of WP, it's code in a plugin or theme that's calling a deprecated function.